# How to handle an exception without closing application?

Tags: c#, wpf, exception

I have a `try catch` for sending a an email through a WPF C# application as followed:

```
try { smtpmail.Send(message); }
            catch (Exception err) { throw new CustomException("Error contacting server.", err); }
```

However, I don't want the application to stop running/crash if this error is hit. Rather, just change the error to a error message `TextBox` I have set up within the application...or something related to NOT crashing the application and rather informing the user to try again later (or if problem persists: contact so-and-so).

*Edit:* Expectation: Error to be logged, but user sees this,

```
errorMsg.Text = "Error contacting server. Try again later, or if problem persists contact Billy Bob Boo";
```

How do I go about implementing this?

**Update:** Apologies for the unclear question. Basically I needed help on how to go about logging my error but display a friendly error message to the user...but I asked it poorly. Using the comments and answer provided, I researched a bit more answered my own question below. Thanks, everyone! :)

Comment: If you are going to throw, you need to catch somewhere.

Comment: If you don't want an error to be thrown, why are you catching the error then throwing another exception?

Comment: Maybe an exception is thrown (and your program crashes) because you're throwing an exception. You catch it, but the re-throw it. Either catch   the error farther up the chain and log it/display an error message (but don't crash the program) or do that here.

Comment: @Savanna I catch and declare exception `err`, but don't use it anywhere. I don't want the user to know exactly what the error is, so I throw a `CustomException`

Comment: Where are you stuck? Do you know how to put text into a textbox? What part of the solution is confusing you?

Comment: @justinternio Okay, so catch it and just show a generic error message and log the dirty secret elsewhere.

Comment: @tnw Wondering how to do that. I want to catch and log the error, and just display an error message to the user using an already implemented error message `TextBox`

Comment: @justinternio That's three things you mentioned right there. Which one are you having trouble with?

Comment: @justinternio Have you attempted to research this *at all*? I guarantee if you Google around for 5 minutes you'll be able to figure out how to display an error message and log the exception.

Comment: @tnw I apologize. I likely didn't use the best terminology to research what I wanted to do. I had this `try catch` set up days ago because I ran into the error once and didn't want the user to see the specifics of the error and saw using a `CustomException` as a solution at the time.

Comment: Where is the question .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How I went about in solving my issue:

```
bool success = false;
            try { 
                //try to send the message
                smtpmail.Send(message);
                success = true;//everything is good
            }
            catch (Exception err)
            {
                //error with sending the message
                errorMsg.Text = ("Unable to send mail at this time. Please try again later.");

                //log the error 
                errorLog.Log(err); //note errorLog is another method to log the error


                //other stuff relating to certain parts of the application visibility

            }
            finally
            {
                if (success)
                { 
                    //what to do if the email was successfully sent
                }
            }
```

Comment: Why the success flag? Simply put those operations after the `smtpmail.Send()`. Finally block should be used to execute code no matter if an exception was thrown or not.

Answer (score 0):

Why are you catching the exception and then throwing it again? That doesn't seem very effective.

You could use a messagebox...

```
try { 
    smtpmail.Send(message); 
}catch (Exception err) { 
    MessageBox.Show(err.Message, "Exception", MessageBoxButton.OK, MessageBoxImage.Error);
}
```

EDIT: You just said you don't wantd the user to know about the exception. Well, then just leave the catch block empty :)

Comment: `just leave the catch block empty` this is bad advice. The exception should at least be logged, an error message (not necessarily revealing details) should also be shown.

Comment: @tnw I just said that because he said he doesn't want to use it anywhere and doesn't want to user to know about it. But you're right, he should at least log it to a file or something.

Comment: Yeah, I want to log it somewhere at least. Answer works though, even though I'll make a few tweaks to it so the user doesn't go forward into the completion page. xD